# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' (New coder, what am I doing wrong here)

Tags: python, if-statement

Brand new to coding and I wanted to get more familiar with if/elif. My code errors out but I am not sure why.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

This is the error I receive, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

#Chunk of Code#

```
print('Enter a name')
name = input()
print('What is you age?')
age = input()
if name == [] #Here I have an array of 2800 names#
print('Hi' +  name )
elif age < 12:
print('You are not allowed here kiddo.')
elif age > 2000:
print('Unlike you I am not an undead, immortal vampire.')
elif age > 100:
print('You are not allowed here boomer, please leave.')
```

Comment: What is your code? We can't tell you what you did wrong if you do not provide your code. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A guess but you're probably taking in user input, which is returned as a string, and not properly converting it to an integer.

Comment: Cast the string as an `int`.

`int(my_string_variable) < my_int_variable`

Answer (score 0):

**< is a comparison operator in PYTHON.** Therefore we can only compare int with int and strings with strings. We cannot compare int with strings.

```
output1 = "a" < "b"

output2 =  2 < 3

print(output1)
print(output2)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
True
```

**If your number is a string, use following method to compare.**

```
output1 = int("2") < int("3")

print(output1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
```

In the code which is provided by you, input age is a string , that is why it pops up the error.

***SOLUTION***

Convert input age into int when it is entered like below.

```
age = int(input())
```